# how to combine these 2 sql queries in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these table, mega avatar is child of avatar which have mother and father.

```
avatar (avatarID,playerID,speciesName,charName,avatarDob,strength,gender,hoard)
```

`megaAvatar(megaAvatarID,charName,megaAvatarDob,speciesName,magicPower,hoard,gender)`

```
relationship(relationshipID,megaAvatarID,fatherAvaID,motherAvaID)
```

> how to combine these 2 queries into one which can display father(avatar) and mother(avatar) details

```
    SELECT megaAvatar.charName, megaAvatar.speciesName, megaAvatar.magicPower,
            avatar.charName AS fatherName, avatar.speciesName AS fatherSpeciesName, 
species.speciesCost AS fatherSpeciesCost        
    FROM megaAvatar 
    INNER JOIN relationship ON megaAvatar.megaAvatarID = relationship.megaAvatarID
    INNER JOIN avatar ON relationship.fatherAvaID = avatar.avatarID
    INNER JOIN species ON avatar.speciesName = species.speciesName

    WHERE megaAvatar.hoard > 16;



SELECT megaAvatar.charName, megaAvatar.speciesName, megaAvatar.magicPower,
        avatar.charName AS motherName, avatar.speciesName AS motherSpeciesName, species.speciesCost AS motherSpeciesCost
FROM megaAvatar 
INNER JOIN relationship ON megaAvatar.megaAvatarID = relationship.megaAvatarID
INNER JOIN avatar ON relationship.motherAvaID = avatar.avatarID
INNER JOIN species ON avatar.speciesName = species.speciesName

WHERE megaAvatar.hoard > 16;
```

Comment: Your title says Oracle, but you have a mySQL tag.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it in Oracle SQL as I don't have it ... but it works in other DBMS ...

The idea is to join again on the same table and use different aliases ..

```
SELECT megaAvatar.charName, megaAvatar.speciesName, megaAvatar.magicPower,
        fatherAvatar.charName AS fatherName, fatherAvatar.speciesName AS fatherSpeciesName, 
        motherAvatar.charName AS motherName, motherAvatar.speciesName AS motherSpeciesName, 
        fatherSpecies.speciesCost AS fatherSpeciesCost, motherSpecies.speciesCost AS motherSpeciesCost
    FROM megaAvatar 
    INNER JOIN relationship ON megaAvatar.megaAvatarID = relationship.megaAvatarID

    INNER JOIN avatar as fatherAvatar ON relationship.fatherAvaID = fatherAvatar.avatarID
    INNER JOIN species as fatherSpecies ON fatherAvatar.speciesName = fatherSpecies.speciesName

    INNER JOIN avatar as motherAvatar ON relationship.motherAvaID = motherAvatar.avatarID
    INNER JOIN species as motherSpecies ON motherAvatar.speciesName = motherSpecies.speciesName

    WHERE megaAvatar.hoard > 16;
```

Comment: just try in oracle , return ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: @ChanKeanYeow - As I said I don't have Oracle on my system and hence  cant try ... but it works on other DBMS so it should work for Oracle also...

Can you elaborate whats the error .. 
The concept is that you can join multiple times on the same table using different alias

Comment: missig a FROM keyword